# Socket DataOutputStream writeInt() method NullPointerException

Tags: sockets, nullpointerexception, dataoutputstream

I'm trying to send serialize class object on the server side. First I serialize object in byte array, then I take array length and send lenght as integer and send array on the srever side. But programm fold with NullPointerException in stacktrace. All class-fields is static. What a problem?

```
public class Main {

public static int port = 8085;
public static String address = "127.0.0.1";
public static Socket clientSocket;
public static InputStream in;
public static OutputStream out;
public static DataInputStream din;
public static DataOutputStream dout;
public static boolean stop = false;
public static int l;

public Main(){
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
        clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
        in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        din = new DataInputStream(in);
        dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int number = 5;
    String str = "Hello world!";
    byte[] bt = str.getBytes();
    ArrayList<Byte> array = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    for(int i=0; i<bt.length; i++){
        array.add(bt[i]);
    }
    while(!stop){
        Template protocol = new Template(number, str, array);
        byte[] serializeObject = SerializationUtils.serialize(protocol);
        l = serializeObject.length;
        try {
            dout.writeInt(l); //NPE
            dout.write(serializeObject); //NPE
            dout.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're invoking the static field `dout` without it being initialized. By default, Java object references are initialized to `null`. The code that initializes those fields is in the constructor, which is not being called since you're inside the static `main()` method, which is not tied to an instance. So your reference is still `null`, hence the `NullPointerException` when you invoke your `dout.writeInt(l);`.

Unless you explicitly create a `Main()` instance, as in `Main myMain = new Main();`, your main method needs to initialize your `dout` reference, since it's `null`.

Since this seems more like a simple communication test, just move the initialization code in the constructor to your main method.